# Can't include SDL_ttf.h using MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl, sdl-ttf

I'm trying to make a cookie clicker clone and when I include the SDL_ttf header file, I get an error. How do I resolve this error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2\SDL.h>
#include "..\SDL2_ttf-2.0.15\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2\SDL_ttf.h"
```

I compile with:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -I../SDL2-2.0.16/i686-w64-mingw32/include -L../SDL2-2.0.16/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

I got this error message:

```
In file included from test.cpp:3:0:
..\SDL2_ttf-2.0.15\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2\SDL_ttf.h:34:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
 #include "SDL.h"
```

I'm on a windows machine (windows 10) and using sublime.

Comment: Firstly, use `/` instead of ``\``. Second, don't use long relative paths. `#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf>`, and use `-I...` flag to add the include directory to the search path, like you did with the other one.

Answer (score -1):

Put the -lSDL2_ttf flag in the compile line

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).